# How to run Opendaylight in Reactive mode?

Tags: wireshark, mininet, sdn, opendaylight, openflow

I use Opendaylight Nitrogen and it runs in proactive mode with L2-Switch module. Yet, somehow I couldnt find a clue how to make it work in reactive mode.

The reason to do is I try to see FLOW_MOD messages after after PACKET_IN. I appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it L2 switch only or L2 switch with Openflow on top?
With L2 switch, you can configure the arp flooding, so to have it proactive or reactive, you can check below:
https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-nitrogen/user-guide/l2switch-user-guide.html

If you enable openflow-plugin, each time a switch sends a new flows, you can see the Packet-IN traces using wireshark or openswitch dumps.

Also you can look at this:
https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_SDN_Controller_Platform_(OSCP):Overview

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The L2switch flood proactive mode has little or nothing to do with OpenFlow proactive mode. The first means controller does not flood received ARP packets (PACKET_IN) because those are handled by the data plane while the second means controller does not program flows based on received traffic (PACKET_IN).

Now if you want to force an OpenFlow reactive behavior (e.g. for test purposes) you can use the drop test application that will send a drop flow for every received PACKET_IN, to do that:

1) Install the drop test feature:

opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-openflowplugin-drop-test

2) Enable the drop:

opendaylight-user@root>dropAllPacketsRpc on